# checking for timezones which dont follow DST?

Tags: php, date, time, format

My code works fine for converting any timezone into GMT/UTC and vice-versa. 
But i want the functionality where it should also check for those timezones which are not following DST and also should include the functionality where the date/time can be in any format.

Means if simply date is entered it should give me the correct result.
For eample:

If i entered just '2011-03-31' or date in any format it it should give me the correct result.
This is my code.

```
function ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($time,$currentTimezone,$timezoneRequired,$requried_DST=true) {

  date_default_timezone_set($currentTimezone);
  $current_time = strtotime($time);
  date_default_timezone_set($timezoneRequired);

  if (!$requried_DST && (date('I', $current_time) == 1))
   {
          if ($timezoneRequired == 'Australia/Lord_Howe')
             $dst='-30 minutes';
          else $dst = "-1 hour";
        $current_time = strtotime($dst, $current_time);

    }
          // restore old timezone
          $res = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_time);
          return $res;
  }
```

please anybody help me.

here is an example ......
my inputs are........

```
    $mytime = '2011-03-31 2:35:00.000';
    $myzone = 'America/New_York';

    echo  "(New_York->UTC DST=Yes)".ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($mytime, $myzone, 'UTC', true) ."<br>";
    echo "(New_York->UTC DST=No)".ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($mytime, $myzone, 'UTC', false) . " <br><br>";

///////////////////////

$mytime = '2011-03-31 6:35:00.000';
$myzone = 'UTC';

echo  "(UTC->New_York DST=Yes)".ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($mytime, $myzone, 'America/New_York', true) ."<br>";
echo "(UTC->New_York DST=No)".ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($mytime, $myzone, 'America/New_York', false) . " <br><br>";
```

and 
the result is:

```
(New_York->UTC DST=Yes)2011-03-31 06:35:00
(New_York->UTC DST=No)2011-03-31 06:35:00

(UTC->New_York DST=Yes)2011-03-31 02:35:00
(UTC->New_York DST=No)2011-03-31 01:35:00
```

............here date entered can be in anyformat...........

Comment: Why do you return `strftime($res);`? That won't work because `strftime()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid format string.

Comment: PHPs date and time functions were mostly useless back when I needed them. If are worth their name in current versions you should not need to worry about DST, it should account for it when you set the desired timezone. So if they do not, please provide an example ; )

Comment: Sorry but your example doesn't make sense. Timezone `America/New_York` changed from standard to daylight saving time on March 13th this year, so forcing another DST adjustment results in a false point in time.

Comment: in my code i gave this format,  $res = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_time); for getting the result right.......here that date format should not be static .it should vary,if user enters just date or both datetime as input i must get the same result.

Comment: Didn't get you last comment...

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to do this should be (although I don't understand your `$requried_DST` switch)

```
function ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone($time, $currentTimezone, $timezoneRequired) {
    $dt = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($currentTimezone));
    $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezoneRequired));
    return $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Example:

```
echo ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone('2011-03-31 12:00', 'Europe/Berlin', 'UTC');
// 2011-03-31 10:00:00 that's two hours difference because of DST
echo ConvertOneTimezoneToAnotherTimezone('2011-03-12 12:00', 'Europe/Berlin', 'UTC');
// 2011-03-12 11:00:00 that was before DST transition last weekend
```

Comment: $requried_DST will check for the condition where timezone conversion must be done for Daylight saving and without daylight saving also.

Comment: The need for a DST correction is determined by the timezone and the point in time you're looking at. Or are you trying to something like *what would happen if timezone x/y didn't switch to DST?*

Comment: i need to write a php script which should convert any time zone into UTC and vice-versa.ok.So while doing this itshould check for countries that follow DST and not DST.also check that date/time can be entered in any format but should convert into UTC correctly.

Comment: The code I provided above does exactly what you want. No need to fiddle with DST yourself. To use your function correctly you'd need to know if the given point in time in the given timezone is using DST.

Comment: your code does not work for DST.that means if i want UTC format of America/New_York i am getting correct result.but when i convert back from UTC to America/New_York i should get result by considering DSt and wihtout also.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want to know what time 2011-03-31 12:00 (UTC) is in New York, there is only one correct solution - the one in DST because New York switched to DST on 2011-03-13.